# Adding dynamic content with events in jquerymobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Currently I'm stuck with a problem in jquerymobile: I'm adding items to a list dynamically and use enhanceWithin() in the end (so styling is correct).
After this I like to add click-events for each list item but the problem is, that enhanceWithin runs asynchronous and so I always get the error message "cannot call methods on checkboxradio prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'"

When I delay the event-adding-code it works perfectly.

Does anyone have an idea if there is a enhanceWithin.done event or anything else I can use?

HTML:

```
...
<div id="shoppinglist">Loading list...</div>
...
```

Javascript:

```
function updateList()
{
    var result = "";

    $.each(shoppinglistItems, function (index, item) {
        result += '<label><input type="checkbox" ' + item.checked + ' id="item_' + item.id + '">' + item.name + '</label>\n';
    });

    $('#shoppinglist').html(result).enhanceWithin();

    // Change-Events an die Checkboxen knoten
    $('input[id*=item_]').unbind('change').bind('change', function (event) {
        var itemid = $(this).attr('id');
        itemid = (itemid.split('_'))[1];    // Nur die Zahl extrahieren
        // Passendes Item aus der Liste der Items suchen und checken
        $.each(shoppinglistItems, function (index, item) {
            if (item.id == itemid)
            {
                item.checked = "checked";
                item.timestamp = moment().format("YYYYMMDDHHmmss");
            }
        });
        updateList();
    });
}
```

Comment: Add code to clarify the problem.

Comment: Change this `$('input[id*=item_]').unbind('change').bind('change', function (event) {` to this `$(document).on('change', 'input[id*=item_]', function (event) {`

Comment: Thanks again, but it still produces the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you using `.checkboxradio("refresh")`?

Comment: Nope, only the code posted above. I changed the JS-code and added my function so that it becomes clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Omar's advice of using event delegation should work for you. In my example below, I call updatelist on pagecreate to initially create the checkboxes. Then I use event delegation (on()) to create the change handler on any inputs within the shoppinglist DIV whether they exist right now or not. the line $("#shoppinglistItemsCont").html(JSON.stringify(shoppinglistItems)); simply prints the contents of the object to the screen so you can see it change.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){

    $("#shoppinglistItemsCont").html(JSON.stringify(shoppinglistItems));
    updateList();

    $("#shoppinglist").on("change", "input[id*=item_]", function(event){
        var itemid = $(this).attr('id');
        itemid = (itemid.split('_'))[1];    // Nur die Zahl extrahieren
        // Passendes Item aus der Liste der Items suchen und checken
        $.each(shoppinglistItems, function (index, item) {
            if (item.id == itemid)
            {
                item.checked = "checked";
                item.timestamp = moment().format("YYYYMMDDHHmmss");                
            }
        });
        updateList();    
        $("#shoppinglistItemsCont").html(JSON.stringify(shoppinglistItems));
    });

});


function updateList()
{
    var result = "";
    $.each(shoppinglistItems, function (index, item) {
        result += '<label><input type="checkbox" ' + item.checked + ' id="item_' + item.id + '">' + item.name + '</label>\n';
    });

    $('#shoppinglist').html(result).enhanceWithin();
}
```

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8LKte/)**

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to create this example. And yes, it is working for me like you said. My problem is, that the list is refreshed when an item is checked (checked items are sorted down) and then rerendered with updatelist(). The first time, the list is created all is working well (like in your example). As soon as the list is modified by clicking an item the error is thrown.

Comment: @ChristianWaidner, Can you update my fiddle to make the error happen?

Comment: I modified the Fiddle you provided for me and added the sort function I'm using => the error is now thrown. Basically I want to create a shopping list where checked items are sorted down. Thank you very much for your continued support in this.

Comment: @ChristianWaidner, after modifying the fiddle, click update and then post the new link address here.

Comment: Sorry @ezanker for being a total noob. I thought clicking update is enough that your original code will be updated. The new link is http://jsfiddle.net/8LKte/2/, I added my sort to make it clear.

Comment: @ChristianWaidner, I am running your fiddle in Chrome Ver 35 and it works fine (each time I click an item, the list resorts with unchecked items at the top). Are you seeing the problems in a particular browser maybe?

Comment: I also use Chrome 35 and technically it works (resort etc.). But when I open the JS console (F12) I got the mentioned error message and I just want to know what can I do to prevent this to avoid future problems.

Comment: I see the error in the console. I don't know what is causing it, or how to avoid it.